# How do I convert a mouse click x value to a value in the domain of a x-axis in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created an x-axis in d3 like the following. Note that the data.x has a min of -3 and a max of +3.

```
var data = [ {x:-3, y:20}, {x:3, y:10}, ... {x:-2, y:15} ];
var xmin = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.x; });
var xmax = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.x; });
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([xmin, xmax]).range([0, 220]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom');
d3.select(this).append('g')
 .on('click', function(d) { 
  var xPos = d3.event.x; //how do i convert this value to a valid value on the x-axis?
 })
 .call(xAxis);
```

Is there a util function on the `xAxis` or `x` object that allows me to map the x value of where the mouse was clicked to a value on the domain of the x-axis?

The problem is detailed here on plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/RFOoYxtBgNPcV4cnR4F5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
.on('click', function(d) { 
  var xPos = x.invert(d3.event.x); 
 })
```

Here function x is

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([xmin, xmax]).range([0, 220]);
```

Comment: should `x(d3.event.x)` give me a value between `xmin` and `xmax`? because it is currently giving me a value way outside those ranges.

Comment: `x.invert` doesn't work. Please see the updated example on plnkr.

Comment: I would suggest you to use this `  str += 'x.invert(mouse.x) = ' + x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);` instead of `  str += 'x.invert(mouse.x) = ' + x.invert(d3.event.x);` fiddle here http://plnkr.co/edit/X71u1jxl4rxucmMIn17W?p=preview